# How to retrieve text from database without its formatting tags

Tags: php, mysql

I want to retrieve (select) 200 characters from a MySQL table, but the text is formatted. So when I use:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, status, password, SUBSTRING(description,1,200) as description FROM forsale_content WHERE status='online' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15";
```

It will give me the description text, but if it's formatted as bold or has something like a <h1> tag, it will destroy my design.

What command should I use to retrieve those characters without their formatting tags?

Comment: use strip_tags() function in Your php tag

Comment: I also suggest you do it by PHP - this will lower the charge on MySQL and PHP can do it more ... easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. You have to format your description field with PHP, by execute an algorithm which closes HTML tag opens before the cut.
2. Apply [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.strip-tags.php) when you print the string substracted in MySQL.

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems I need to study php a lot more :)